# React component failed to render in production mode when i use npm run build and serve -s build

Tags: reactjs, express, production

```
react-dom.production.min.js:209 TypeError: e.map is not a function
at a.value (Appointment.js:32)
at Ua (react-dom.production.min.js:182)
at La (react-dom.production.min.js:181)
at vl (react-dom.production.min.js:263)
at cu (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
at lu (react-dom.production.min.js:246)
at Zl (react-dom.production.min.js:239)
at react-dom.production.min.js:123
at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:19)
at Vo (react-dom.production.min.js:122)
```

el @ react-dom.production.min.js:209

I have an error and its pops when running my project in production mode, that is when I use npm run build and serve -s build.  In development mode, its does work well so maybe if someone can help me figure it out.
I use express api for backend.

Comment: In `Appointment.js` line 32 there's a `map()` function being called but the property `map` does not exist, you're probably trying to map over a value that isn't an array.

Comment: could that possibly mean that my array is empty?

Comment: @webWalker it shouldn't trigger '.map' error on empty array. Probably initial value type is wrong. Or when you fetch data, you get not an array back

Comment: @SergejKlackovskis thank you so much i realized the problem was with **fetching data** it wasn't returning an array.